# Grepping for NVM version doesn't seem to work to detect my version and then install it

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, terminal, nvm

I am scripting an install of a specific NVM Node version. I wrote this code in my script:

```
# Check for NVM Node 8.12.0, install if it does not exist.
if [[ $(nvm ls | grep 8.12.0) == "" ]]; then
  nvm install 8.12.0
  echo "nvm which current"
  nvm use 8.12.0
else
  nvm use 8.12.0
fi
```

However, when I run this, I get:

```
N/A: version "8.12.0 -> N/A" is not yet installed.
You need to run "nvm install 8.12.0" to install it before using it.
```

If I run a check for installed NVM versions `nvm ls`, I get:

```
->      v8.11.3
default -> 8.11.3 (-> v8.11.3)
node -> stable (-> v8.11.3) (default)
stable -> 8.11 (-> v8.11.3) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.14.4 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.12.0 (-> N/A)
```

My `.bashrc` file has:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

So I am not sure where I am gong wrong.  I suspect it's `if [[ $(nvm ls | grep 8.12.0) == "" ]]; then` that is not doing what I think it's doing, to check to see if NVM node 8.12.0 is already installed.

Comment: `grep` returns "true" (0) and "false" (1) wnen the target is found/not found. You should be able to reduce your code `if ! nvm ls | grep 8.12.0 ; then ... ; else ... ; fi`. Good luck.

Comment: Actually it  `[[ $(node -v) != "v8.12.0" ]]; then` which works.